# Cloudwatch agent not sending logs(/var/log/secure) to cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I am trying to use cloudwatch-agent to collect ec2's memory and /var/log/secure logs.
ec2 memory is monitored. However, it does not collect /var/log/secure logs.

So currently I collect /var/log/secure with awslogsd.
Cloudwatch-agent is used for monitoring ec2 memory.

But I want to collect logs from /var/log/secure without using awslogsd.

Even though I set up my test server to only install cloudwatch-agent, no logs are collected in /var/log/secure.

The way I configured the cloudwatch agent is as follows.

The installation progress is as follows.

`sudo yum install amazon-cloudwatch-agent -y`
`cd /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/`
`sudo vim config.json`

This is my config.json file.

```
    {
    "agent": {
      "metrics_collection_interval": 10,
      "logfile": "/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/logs/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.log",
      "run_as_user": "root"
    },
    "logs": {
        "logs_collected": {
          "files": {
           "collect_list": [
              {
                "file_path": "/var/log/secure",
                "log_group_name": "test/sercure",
                "log_stream_name": "{instance_id}"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
    "metrics": {
      "namespace": "test",
      "metrics_collected": {
       "swap": {
         "measurement": [
           "swap_used",
           "swap_free",
           "swap_used_percent"
         ]
       },
       "mem": {
         "measurement": [
           "mem_used",
           "mem_cached",
           "mem_total"
         ],
         "metrics_collection_interval": 1
       }
     },
     "append_dimensions": {
       "ImageId": "${aws:ImageId}",
       "InstanceId": "${aws:InstanceId}",
       "InstanceType": "${aws:InstanceType}"
     }
   }
 }
```

This is the iam permission you gave to ec2.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cloudwatch:PutMetricData",
                "ec2:DescribeVolumes",
                "ec2:DescribeTags",
                "logs:PutLogEvents",
                "logs:DescribeLogStreams",
                "logs:DescribeLogGroups",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:CreateLogGroup"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ssm:GetParameter"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ssm:*:*:parameter/AmazonCloudWatch-*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Also CloudWatchFullAccess, AmazonEC2RoleforSSM, CloudWatchEventsFullAccess I also gave permission.

After that

```
`sudo ./amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl -a fetch-config -m ec2 file://opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/config.json -s`
```

command was executed.

Running it gives the following result:

```
****** processing amazon-cloudwatch-agent ******
/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/config-downloader --output-dir /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.d --download-source default --mode ec2 --config /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/common-config.toml --multi-config default
I! Trying to detect region from ec2
D! [EC2] Found active network interface
Successfully fetched the config and saved in /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.d/default.tmp
Start configuration validation...
/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/config-translator --input /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.json --input-dir /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.d --output /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.toml --mode ec2 --config /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/common-config.toml --multi-config default
2023/07/04 09:05:39 Reading json config file path: /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.d/default.tmp ...
2023/07/04 09:05:39 I! Valid Json input schema.
I! Detecting run_as_user...
I! Trying to detect region from ec2
D! [EC2] Found active network interface
No csm configuration found.
No log configuration found.
Configuration validation first phase succeeded
/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/amazon-cloudwatch-agent -schematest -config /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.toml
Configuration validation second phase succeeded
Configuration validation succeeded
```

I installed
sudo amazon-linux-extras collectd
but nothing changed.

i got amazon-cloudwatch-agent.toml is shown below.

```
[agent]
  collection_jitter = "0s"
  debug = false
  flush_interval = "1s"
  flush_jitter = "0s"
  hostname = ""
  interval = "60s"
  logfile = "/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/logs/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.log"
  logtarget = "lumberjack"
  metric_batch_size = 1000
  metric_buffer_limit = 10000
  omit_hostname = false
  precision = ""
  quiet = false
  round_interval = false

[inputs]

  [[inputs.disk]]
    fieldpass = ["used_percent"]
    tagexclude = ["mode"]
    [inputs.disk.tags]
      metricPath = "metrics"

  [[inputs.mem]]
    fieldpass = ["used_percent"]
    [inputs.mem.tags]
      metricPath = "metrics"

[outputs]

  [[outputs.cloudwatch]]
    force_flush_interval = "60s"
    namespace = "CWAgent"
    region = "us-west-2"
    tagexclude = ["host", "metricPath"]
    [outputs.cloudwatch.tagpass]
      metricPath = ["metrics"]

[processors]

  [[processors.ec2tagger]]
    ec2_instance_tag_keys = ["aws:autoscaling:groupName"]
    ec2_metadata_tags = ["ImageId", "InstanceId", "InstanceType"]
    refresh_interval_seconds = "0s"
    [processors.ec2tagger.tagpass]
      metricPath = ["metrics"]
```

My config file doesn't seem to be taking effect.

/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/logs/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.log No error pops up.

Why am I not getting the /var/log/secure log?

Comment: If not resolved, we will collect /var/log/secure with awslogsd and monitor mem with cloudwatch-agent as before.

Comment: It's resolved.
1. Indentation issue in config.json (not sure)
2. sudo /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl -a import config -m ec2 -c file:/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/config. json -s
Apply the configuration with this command and restart.
3. Part of my test was to delete the "agent" - "logfile" line from config.json.
Check the "file_path" path and file name in "logs" (otherwise the logs will not accumulate).

After that, it operates normally while checking log-related values ​​in input and output in amazon-cloudwatch-agent.toml.